# Django getstream User object is not iterable

Tags: django, getstream-io

i try to integrate Django with Getstream. Mostly code work, but at the end on profile page, i have error: "User object is not iterable".

I follow tutorial get stream Twitter, and search through Getstream pinterest example. I have the same code, but for me don't work. Try both, getstream Twitter profile view and pinterest style profile view. Both the same error.

View:

```
def user_detail(request, username):
   '''
    Shows the users profile
    '''
    enricher = Enrich(request.user)
    profile_user = get_user_model().objects.get(username=username)
    feed = feed_manager.get_user_feed(profile_user.id)
    activities = feed.get(limit=25)['results']
    context = {}
    do_i_follow_users(request.user, [profile_user])
    context['profile_user'] = profile_user
    context['activities'] = enricher.enrich_activities(activities)
    response = render(request, 'account/user/detail.html', context)
    return response
```

When I check getstream dashboard I see log of actions:
[Screen getstream dashboard log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH081.png)

What are the other options to interate through user. I need only user timeline on this page.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear, to say so.

Somewhere in your code you're passing a single instance of `User` objects while the function itself expects a list of them or a list of something else.

After a really quick google search (bear with me, I haven't used `GetStream` yet) I think you can also instantiate `enricher = Enrich()` without passing the `User` object.

Comment: you get error 'Object of type User is not JSON serializable' if you remove the single user arg.